# I want a sprite button that fades

Tags: jquery, css

I think sprites is the best thing about css that helps gain insane speed on any site.
I need you guys to help me build a 'hover' handler that crossfades the sprites.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The best way to get the most out of this site is not to say "build this for me", but to try to do it yourself, and ask specific questions when you fail. So see how far you can get on your own first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tutorial right on the subject:
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites2/

Answer (score 1):

Check out the tutorial:

- [Image Cross Fade Transition with jQuery](http://css.dzone.com/news/jquery-image-cross-fade-transi)